# Client Certs for WCF consumer stops working after a while

Tags: wcf, client

I am having really peculiar issue with certs not working after a while for WCF Client App that connect to SOAP 1.1 SAP service. What boggles me is the steps I have to take to make the certs work again. After I installed the certs on couple of load balanced servers, seems like everything works fine. But then after a few days, one of the app/servers throws this error.

**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

When I log on to the server using MMC and open the cert (I do not even have to reinstall it, just open is good enough), the web app works. I am at my wits end as to why this might be happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Below are the architecture/some code samples of how the apps/web services are set up

[MVC WebApp]--[ Load Balancer ]-->(Server 1, Server 2)--> SAP SOAP 1.0 Web Service

Some configuration and code samples..

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://somesapwebservice:8104/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=BC_PORTAL&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=SI_AppFormData_Out_Sync&amp;interfaceNamespace=urn%3Acominc.com%3AOTC%3AI1053%3AppForm" behaviorConfiguration="secureCert" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="somecontract_Out_Sync" name="HTTPS_Port" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="secureCert">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" findValue="CN=CNN, OU=Windows, OU=SAP, OU=Service Accounts, OU=Admin, OU=CORP, DC=myinc, DC=ds" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
    ..

<appSettings>
<add key="ProtocolExceptionMessage" value="The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)" />
```

C# Code

```
public ActionResult FormSubmit(SubmitViewModel model) 

try
{
    this.SubmitToSAPService(model);
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Complete");
}
catch (ProtocolException pe)
{
    // Current SAP only support SOAP 1.1 and WCF with .NET 4.6 runs on SOAP 1.2 - Catching the known exception
    // Creating custom WCF binding to handle this is another possibility but that config could get convoluted
    var messageSnippet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProtocolExceptionMessage"];

    if (pe.Message.Contains(messageSnippet))
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Complete");
    }

    throw pe;
}
```

One thing I am doing little off here is that I was told is that SAP is currently running SAOP 1.1 and .NET we are running is SOAP 1.2. So I was always getting Protocol Exception. To get around that I check for the text and if the exception  message matches exactly as expected,  I bypass it.

```
public string SubmitToSAPService(SubmitViewModel model)
{
var dtFormDataRecords = new DT_FormData();

dtFormDataRecords.Records = new DT_FormDataRecords();

dtFormDataRecords.Records.Name = model.name
....

var client = new SI_AppFormData_Out_SyncClient();             
try
{
client.SI_AppFormData_Out_Sync(dtFormDataRecords);
}
finally
{
client.Close();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to run intellitrace on the app, that let to clue me in the app-pool settings Load User Profile was set to False. That had cause the issue I was getting. After I set the it to True, my issue was resolved.